# How to link against the URdriver(driver.py) from a ROS node

Tags: ros, driver, node, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I working on UR5 these days. As far as I understood, UR driver(driver.py) in universal package acts like an interface between ROS and URScripts. My question is how I can link a ROS node with this driver From my node. I need to get the torque of joints. To do so, I put two functions in both URscripts and UR driver (driver.py) to be able to communicate with each other but I do not know how to connect my node with UR driver and send command to it from my node. Dose anybody know how?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216274/how-to-link-against-the-urdriver(driver.py)-from-a-ros-node/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@mig is right (I'm just clarifying some details): the `ur_driver` package contains a Python ROS node that connects though TCP/IP to the URScript portion of the driver that runs on the UR controller.

Commanding it is done using `FollowJointTrajectory` actions, and robot state data is broadcast using appropriate publishers (`JointState`, `WrenchStamped`, etc). See also the `ur_driver` [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/ur_driver).

> As far as I understood, UR driver(driver.py) in universal package acts like an interface between ROS and URScripts.

Not really. The driver is really only meant to make it possible for ROS nodes to control the arm using an actionlib client, and to receive information about the state of the arm by subscribing to the topics provided. It is possible to extend the driver (both the Python and the URScript side) to do whatever you want, but that is not what the driver was necessarily designed for.

So all-in-all there is no *linking* (in the traditional compiled language sense) involved. Follow @mig's advise, and send the appropriate messages to the provided topics and / or invoke services on the `ur_driver` node. To receive robot state, subscribe to the `/joint_states` and other topics. This should be no different from how you work with other ROS nodes.

PS: an older version of the driver did publish joint torques in the `effort` field of the [JointState](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html) message, but this was removed when the driver was moved to a different state interface (see [universal_robot/issues/125](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/125)). You might want to comment on issue 125 to let the maintainers know that this should be fixed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not quite sure what your question is.

the `driver.py` publishes `JointStates` as well as `Wrench` messages. So you can get the torque at the TCP at least by listening to the respective topics. As far as I see, you need to implement a new publisher for getting torques at the different joints (if this can be retrieved from the UR5, I'm no expert there).

For commanding it, you need to send a `FollowJointTrajectoryAction` from a respective ActionClient.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1